# Is there a way to read EC2InstanceId in Lambda Function(Boto3) passed by SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I am looking to get EC2InstanceId from my Lambda function but somehow I am getting an error `string indices must be integers: TypeError`
Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import re
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    lambda handler function.
    """
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    print(message)
    ec2InstanceId = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['EC2InstanceId']
    print(ec2InstanceId)
```

However, I am getting the following output from `print(message)`:

```
{
    "Progress": 50,
    "AccountId": "*****************",
    "Description": "Launching a new EC2 instance: i-0316df8d5159ee6a7",
    "RequestId": "4b15abf1-7b48-4e9b-528a-891992eabc86",
    "EndTime": "2019-05-28T02:57:46.975Z",
    "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:*****************:autoScalingGroup:*****************:autoScalingGroupName/dynamic-host-asg",
    "ActivityId": "*****************",
    "StartTime": "2019-05-28T02:57:13.747Z",
    "Service": "AWS Auto Scaling",
    "Time": "2019-05-28T02:57:46.975Z",
    "EC2InstanceId": "i-0316df8d5159ee6a7",
    "StatusCode": "InProgress",
    "StatusMessage": "",
    "Details": {
        "Subnet ID": "*****************",
        "Availability Zone": "us-east-1b"
    },
    "AutoScalingGroupName": "dynamic-host-asg",
    "Cause": "At 2019-05-28T02:56:47Z a user request update of AutoScalingGroup constraints to min: 1, max: 2, desired: 1 changing the desired capacity from 0 to 1.  At 2019-05-28T02:57:11Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 1.",
    "Event": "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH"
}
```

But `print(ec2InstanceId)` is giving me following error:

```
string indices must be integers: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
ec2InstanceId = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['EC2InstanceId']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Could you please help me to correct this ?

Comment: What is sending the message to the Amazon SNS topic?

Comment: Are you sure that the message comes back as a JSON object, or is it just a string (which would need to be converted to JSON)?

Comment: Can you just check what you get on printing this stuff as you already have got message `message.get('EC2InstanceId') `

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am not sure, Is there a way to check if it is JSON object or a string? All I am seeing is output from `print(message)` looks json to me

Comment: @amittn I have tried but got an error ```{
  "errorMessage": "'list' object has no attribute 'get'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      27,
      "lambda_handler",
      "print(message.get('EC2InstanceId'))"
    ]```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this

```
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    if isinstance(message, str):
        try:
            message = json.loads(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) 
    elif isinstance(message, list):
        message = message[0]
    asg_instances_list=message['EC2InstanceId']
```